# Google Developer Console Internal Test, Beta and Alpha Track

Tags: android, google-developers-console, testtrack

Can anyone help me understand how I could use Goggle Developer Console Tracks?

I've read [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) right here but I'm still kind of lost. How do I package my application for each of this tracks?

Should I have a different applicationId for each track?

How does the tester get the updated test APKs (since they aren't available in store)?

How to cascade from internal to alpha to beta?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some quick answers:

> Should I have a different applicationId for each track?

Absolutely not. Otherwise they will be completely different applications.

> How does the tester get the updated test APKs (since they aren't available in store)?

Although the app is not *publicly* available in the Play Store, the APKs are distributed through the Play Store once they use your private Opt-In link and add them via their email address.

> How to cascade from internal to alpha to beta?

Not sure about "cascading" but you can "promote" an app upstream from "Internal" -> "Alpha" -> "Beta" -> "Public".

Hope that helps clear things up a little bit.

Comment: I actually forgot I asked this questions by now. I figured all that out after sometime but I marked your answer and upvoted it for others asking the same question in the future :) Thanks!

Comment: had a small doubt , so while signing the app  bundle do i create a build variant for each beta,alpha  and release tracks?. Currently I see only two build variants in android studio  debug and release. So can i sign the release build variant and use it for both beta and release tracks in play console or should i create different build variants for each beta, release ,debug ,and alpha?

Comment: @userrk That's up to you but I believe you can use your `release` build for each of the "Internal", "Alpha", "Beta" and "Public" streams. For example, if you don't have an existing app, you'd likely use the `release` build and just promote it all the way through. But, if you have an existing app released in "Public", you might want to keep your "beta" version in a separate build/branch/flavour so that you can make updates to the `release` build while also working on your "beta" version.